# C++ setting a two dimensional array dimensions based on user input

Tags: c++, arrays

I am attempting to create a two dimensional array depending on the users desired number of rows and columns. I am receiving an error of "use of undeclared identifier 'rows'". I googled and searched on stack overflow but was not able to find a scenario like this, I would like to know what am I doing wrong below is my code :

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Matrix{
    public:
    int matrixDimensions[rows][columns];

    void setMatrix(int x, int y){
        rows = x;
        columns = y;
   }
    int getMatrixDimensions(){
        return rows;
        return columns;

    }



    private:
    int rows;
    int columns;

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int a;
    int b;
    Matrix matrixObject;

    cout << "Please enter the number of rows: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Please enter the number of columns: "<< endl;
    cin >> b;

    matrixObject.setMatrix(a, b);
    cout << "The number of rows and columns are : " << matrixObject.getMatrixDimensions();



    return 0;
}
```

Thank you all feedback is welcomed.I cannot use vectors, thank you for mentioning them but it is not an option here.

Comment: `int matrixDimensions[rows][columns];` is illegal in c++ unless `rows` and `columns` are compile time constants.

Comment: Do you know about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? If not then it's time you learn. Use a vector of vectors.

Comment: Think like a compiler. You see the line `int matrixDimensions[rows][columns];` and you know you have to allocate some memory. How much? That depends on `rows` and `columns` which are symbols you haven't seen yet. Even if you had seen them they don't have any values assigned until after you call `setMatrix()`. Also: Your `getMatrixDimensions()` tells me you need to go back to your text book/ online course / tutor to brush up on some basics.

Comment: Would second the recommendation to use std::vector unless this is an exercise and that isn't allowed, in which case the question should have stated that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Comment: @paisanco *I googled and searched on stack overflow but was not able to find a scenario like this,* -- That sounds like someone looking for any solution, not really a school assignment.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am not looking to have this solved, re-read please I asked for what I am doing wrong not a fix.

Comment: Ugh why are there always constraints like "I cannot use vector" or string or anything from the standard library? What's the point in learning C++

Comment: @Ace *I cannot use vectors* -- You can't use standard arrays, since they're fixed in size at compile-time.  So your attempt will get you nowhere.  Time to learn pointers and `new[]` if you can't use vectors.

Comment: I am just trying to learn and this is part of my course but thank you everyone I believe I know how to fix this mostly thank you @John3136 you clarified my error

Comment: @Ace [Look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048).  That closely as possible mimics a 2-dimensional dynamic array without using vectors, even up to its contiguous nature.

Answer (score -1):

In C++, if you want to declare an array regardless of dimension, you can only declare it before the **compile time**.

For example, let **SIZE** be the user input during **run time**

```
int arr[5]    // OK
int arr[SIZE] // NOT OK
```

If you want to dynamically allocated the array size during the **run time**, you have to use the pointer.

```
int* arr = new int [5] // OK
int* arr = new int [SIZE] // OK
```

Take a look in
[How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Comment: This doesn't really translate well into the code OP posted, as this code is unrelated. How would you recommend they declare `matrixDimensions`

Answer (score -1):

Try declaring the variables rows and columns before the functions. C++ will check the syntax line by line. So it might be the issue.